# Mui Grid vs CSS3 positioning

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning MUI, and I want to know experienced developers's opinions about choosing the best positioning option between the **`<Grid/>` component from MUI** or just use **CSS3 Styling (Flexbox and Grid)**

I used to work with CSS3 positioning, and it is fine and precise especially in responsiveness. I wanna know if `<Grid/>` has no problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

Grid internally uses flexbox as mentioned in the official docs
[here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/)